# How to prevent onDraw's Paint from affecting all rectangles in an ArrayList<Rect>?

Tags: java, android

I have made some code for a drawing app to learn Java in an Android environment.
I can choose to draw freehanded, rectangles, or ovals.
I can also alter Paint attributes, such as line width, color etc.

In order to prevent the shapes from vanishing, each time a new one is drawn, it is added into an ArrayList or ArrayList (ovals)

However, when I use some other code to alter for example line width or FILL, it affects ALL of the shapes which already exist, not just the one i'm currently drawing.

Without the arraylist, the shapes would disappear if I for example switch from drawing rectangles to ovals.

```
float pointX;
float pointY;
float startX;
float startY;
private ArrayList<Rect> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rect>(); //rectangle array




@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // draw background
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen);


        for(Rect rect : rectangles){
            canvas.drawRect(rect,paintLine);

//other additional drawMethods exist here for ovals and freehand pathmap





@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(rectangleDraw){

    pointX = event.getX();
    pointY = event.getY();
// Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = pointX;
            startY = pointY;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            rectangles.add(new Rect((int)startX, (int)startY, (int)pointX, (int)pointY));
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
// Force a view to draw again
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

The issue is that adding into the arraylist takes the form rectangle.add(new Rect(startX,startY,pointX,pointY), and there is no fifth parameter for Paint to save that specific rectangle's style choices, nor does it allow that.
I assume right now the onDraw method takes the whole arraylist, and applies the one single current Paint style on the entire thing.

So what alternative should I use?

[First shape with a set style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MifQ.png)

[The issue: second shape with a new color also changes first shape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebjch.png)

I tried using a Hashmap to store a Rect as key and the Paint object as value, and then iterate through it in the onDraw(), but it still keeps switching styles when the paint's settings are changed. (Refer to images)

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

   canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paintScreen);


        for(Rect rect : rectanglePaint.keySet()){


            canvas.drawRect(rect, rectanglePaint.get(rect));
}



        @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if(rectangleDraw){

    pointX = event.getX();
    pointY = event.getY();
// Checks for the event that occurs
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = pointX;
            startY = pointY;
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            Rect rectX = (new Rect((int)startX, (int)startY, (int)pointX, (int)pointY));
            rectanglePaint.put(rectX, paintLine);

            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
// Force a view to draw again
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can store `Paint` objects in another list with same index as the rect so that when you loop over rect list you assign the right paint or you can go for a `HashMap` which stores key value pairs so your `Rect` object will be the key and `Paint` will be the value.

Comment: I also had the idea to use a HashMap,but for some reason that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Alright it seems I managed to solve my own issue. In addition to using a HashMap, it seems the key was to create a new Paint instance inside the touch event, attaching that to the hashmap as a value.

So stuff like this (not fully ready yet in all getters, but works):

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


    Paint paintRectangle = new Paint();
    paintRectangle.setAntiAlias(true); 
    paintRectangle.setColor(paintLine.getColor()); 
    paintRectangle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paintRectangle.setStrokeWidth(paintLine.getStrokeWidth());  
    paintRectangle.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    Rect rectX = (new Rect((int)startX, (int)startY, (int)pointX, (int)pointY));
    rectanglePaint.put(rectX, paintRectangle);
    break;
```